# How to submit an HTML form so that it triggers a route in Backbone.js?

Tags: html, forms, backbone.js

I am building a tabbed wizard UI in Backbone.js and would like to use the HTML form submission to trigger a route which displays the view for the next tab.  However, the usual submit button doesn't seem to cause the route to fire.

index.html:

```
<form id="stateSearch">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select State:</legend>
        <select name="stateSearchName">
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
            <button type="reset" name="submitStateName"                             onclick="window.location.href='index.html/#searchByState'">Search
            </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

app.js:

```
window.TabExRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'searchByState': 'searchByState'
    },
....
)};
```

I know how to build this using just jQuery but not for Backbone.  I suspect if I create a listener for an ordinary button and then have the listener navigate to the URL it will cause the route to fire.  But, that seems tedious for 6-8 tabs.

I have tried both type="reset" and type="submit" + event.preventDefault() in my JavaScript with the same result.

Is there a canonical pattern for this in Backbone?

Comment: *"I suspect if I create a listener for an ordinary button and then have the listener navigate to the URL it will cause the route to fire. But, that seems tedious for 6-8 tabs."* - why? it's just a single event handler.

Comment: "it's just another event handler" -  Since each form/tab/template is different I would expect each form submission to use a unique event handler.  If that is not the case I am happy to be enlightened

Comment: what is preventing you from identifying which tab is clicked and triggering the respective route using a switch like mechanism in single event handler?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question.   Each tab contains one or more forms with their respective submit buttons.  The user is not clicking on tabs. Rather they are clicking submit or enter on the appropriate form button.   Are you suggesting is is a common pattern for Backbone or just a suggestion on a possible solution?

Comment: The submit buttons will have a similar task right? Nobody wrtes individual handlers for each button/whatever unless the task those things do are extremely different. you said *"HTML form submission to trigger a route which displays the view for the next tab"* so it's a common task I don't see any need for having individiual handlers.